# Array_replace_recursive to values of single array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, each

I have a multidimensional array with an unknown structure and unknown number of items. I need to get a "flater" array compiled from particular keys, like in following example:

**Input**

```
$input = array(

    1 => array(
         'color' => 'blue',
         'haircut' => 'mullet',
         'satisfaction' => 'mild',
         'recursion' => array(...)
    ),

    2 => array(
         'color' => 'green',
         'haircut' => 'mushroom',
         'fashionable' => true,
         'recursion' => array(...)
    ),

    3 => array(
         'color' => 'yellow',
         'haircut' => 'beehive',
         'awkward' => false,
         'recursion' => array(...)
    ),
    
    ...
     
);
```

**Output** (merged array from above)

```
$output = array(
    'color' => 'yellow',
    'haircut' => 'beehive',
    'satisfaction' => 'mild',
    'fashionable' => true,
    'awkward' => false,
    'recursion' => array(...)
);
```

The ideal way, I think, would be to use `array_replace_recursive($input[0],$input[1],$input[2], ...)`, right? The problem is I don't know the exact number of keys in `$input` array.

Is there any easy way how to achieve this? My guess would be to use [`each()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.each.php) function, but to be honest, I never really got that one.

Can you unwrap my head a little bit? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you need:

```
$output = call_user_func_array('array_replace', $input);
```

It calls [`array_replace()`](http://php.net/array_replace) whereby each element of `$input` is passed in as a separate function argument.